# Can I cherry-pick from a perforce repo to another git hub repo?

Tags: github, perforce, git-p4

I have one android project in perforce and one iOS project in github. Same project for different platforms. They share some file. Can I cherrypick certain changes to my github repo from perforce?

Right now, I do the work manually and it is very error-prone. Can I automate the process somehow?

Comment: I've never actually done this, but it seems like it should be possible to do something with `p4 diff2 -du` on the Perforce side and `patch` on the git side.